# Timesnapper / Personal Screen Tracker for MacOS

Tags: video, screen-recording, macos, screenshot

I use a windows app called Timesnapper.

It records everything you do across all your screens the entire day. You can enter a password and playback things that happened through the day. This is useful if you are doing webdev / sysadmin work, and make changes that break things. You go back and see what settings you changed

I can't find a macOS equivalent

I found this superuser thread here, but its quite old

https://superuser.com/questions/213564/timesnapper-for-mac

I checked alternatives and didn't find any to my liking

https://alternativeto.net/software/timesnapper/

Can anyone give me an alternative, either a premade app (paid or free) or a bash-script / applescript workflow?

Comment: It must produce a video, if I understand correctly? What makes it different from all of the screencast apps out there? Is password protection a strong requirement? Please rewrite the question so that it is understandable by people like me who know nothing about Timesnapper and are not inclined to spend time learning about software made for an OS they do not use. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official version of TimeSnapper for Mac is now available!

Affiliation disclosure: I'm the developer of TimeSnapper for Mac! I partnered with the original authors of TimeSnapper for Windows, [Leon Bambrick and Atli Björgvin Oddsson](http://timesnapper.com/about.aspx), to create this official version for macOS.

TimeSnapper for Mac has the same "Play Your Day Like a Movie" as the original TimeSnapper for Windows does:

[image: TimeSnapper for Mac: Play Your Day Like a Movie]

TimeSnapper for Mac's features include:

- Capture of just your active application window, that window's monitor, or all monitors;
- Saving of screen shots in .jpg or .png format;
- Capture of images at resolution and quality percentages ranging from 0 to 100;
- Preview of images directly in the Preferences window, showing the effect of the selected quality settings, including a display of how much space the captured image would consume on disk;
- Automatic cleanup of old image files after a set number of days, and/or when a set amount of disk space has been used by images.

You can find a link to TimeSnapper for Mac on the Apple App Store at the TimeSnapper website (http://timesnapper.com); or, you can jump directly to [TimeSnapper for Mac on the App Store](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/timesnapper/id1456327684?mt=12).

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is a little old but wanted to share that after working on it for more than a year (as a former TimeSnapper user), I've finally released a similar program for macOS: [nnScreenshots](https://www.nearnorthsoftware.com/software/screenshots.php)

For those who are not familiar with this class of software, in general it has the following features (which I've taken as the OP's requirements, please correct me if this is not the case):

- Capture a screenshot of all attached monitors at a set interval
- Allow for browsing of this captured set of screenshots by date
- Allow for rapid scrubbing of a timeline to jump to a particular point in time
- We also provide timesheet entry creation and export right in the application

Commercial application, pricing for this currently is $24.95, same price as TimeSnapper's sale price. Also available on the [Mac App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/nnscreenshots/id1456521714?mt=12).

Screenshots:

[image: main view showing timeline, date selection, play/forward/back controls, and timesheet entry form]

[image: preferences showing settings for image capture]

[image: timesheet view]

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Thanks for answering – but could you please include a few more details? Especially: how does your programm meet the requirements Vincent listed? See [our discussion on what makes an answer high quality](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/356/185) for a guide what about is expected from answers here. Oh: and thanks for disclosing your "affiliation" straight away, thumbs up!

Comment: I remove this answer for now, please add at least a features list, screenshots and license/pricing information. Then we will reopen it. Thanks! :-)